# Why "אִם" used by lending money?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, lending-interest-ribbis, mishpatim, mechilta

In Mishpatim (22:24) the pasuk uses the term "אִם" when describing the mitzvah of lending to the poor.

> אִם-כֶּסֶף תַּלְוֶה אֶת-עַמִּי, אֶת-הֶעָנִי עִמָּךְ--לֹא-תִהְיֶה לוֹ,
>   כְּנֹשֶׁה; לֹא-תְשִׂימוּן עָלָיו, נֶשֶׁךְ
>   [(Mechon-Mamre)](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0222.htm).

Rashi then quotes the Mechilta saying this is one of only 3 places where "אִם" denotes something which isn't optional. At least according to the Mechilta, why does Hashem choose to use this seemingly "optional" lashon by lending?

Comment: Maybe the word just has multiple meaning. Maybe the readers knew what it meant based on a combination of context and tradition?

Comment: The Mechilta seems to take for granted it carries the same meaning (optional) across the board. I agree a word can have different connotations depending on the context or tradition, but it sounds like אִם is something optional the vast majority of the time if there are only 3 exceptions.

Comment: I said nothing about stretching the meaning of a word. I spoke about one word with multiple meanings.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Malbim explains simply that אם means it's a possiblity and might not happen.  Maybe you won't have any money to lend or nobody will need a loan.

Comment: I had a good hunch on that ;-) Although, I have to (re)view the explanation of the verse in prashat *R'eh* that says, "Not such that you will not have a poor person among you." That MAY contradict what Malbim states, here. Stay tuned....

Answer (score 4):

The Maharal in Gur Aryeh explains that the use of אם which connotes רשות as explained in Rashi quoted above by the OP, is meant to signify how one is meant to do charity. Meaning that although it is an obligation to give charity, nonetheless the Torah uses this pharesology of אם to tell us that when one does charity, his giving should not be done out of "rote". As opposed to if one gives by his own accord, he does it with much more simcha

> וזו תשובת בעל גור-אריה: מה שכתוב לשון "אם" אף על גב שהוא חובה, הוא
>   **מפני שאם יעשה מחובה, כאילו מקיים גזירת המלך, אין הדבר לרצון לקדוש ברוך
>   הוא, וצריך שיעשה מרצונו...** ואם עושה אלו שלושה דברים, כאילו מקיים גזירת
>   המלך, אין זה דבר. כי אם בונה מזבח, שזהו עבודתו יתברך להקריב עליו, והוא
>   מקיים מכוח גזירת מלך בלבד, אין זה עבודה, כי העבודה צריך שיהיה עובד לו
>   מרצונו ורק אז נקרא עובד, אבל אם הוא מוכרח אין זה עובד. וכן אם הלוה כסף
>   כאילו מקיים גזירת המלך, אין זה מצוה, כי צריך שילוה לו מרצונו בלב טוב
>   כדכתיב (שם יוד) "נתון תתן לו ולא ירע לבבך", וכן קרבן העומר אשר ציותה
>   התורה להודיע שהוא יתברך, אשר הצמיח לנו הפירות ונתן לנו הכל, וזה צריך
>   הודאה בלב שמאתו ומידו נתן לנו. ואם הוא מקיים המצוה כאילו מוכרח מגזרת
>   המלך, אין זה הודאה, שהוא יתברך עשה את הכל, **ולפיכך צריך לקיים כאילו הוא
>   רשות**

Answer (score 3):

[R. Alshikh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moshe_Alshich) (Exod. 22:24) answers the following:

> הנה אם זה קיימו וקבלו רבותינו ז"ל שהוא ודאי. ואפשר דאפקי בלשון אם בשום לב אל מלת את שבאומרו את העני שהיא מיותרת, לומר אל תיחל מלהלוות עד תהיה בעל זהב, אלא גם אם כסף יהיה לך תלוה את עמי, ועל ידי זה תזכה שאותו שהוא את העני, שהוא הקדוש ברוך הוא כי יעמוד לימין אביון, יהיה עמך ויעשירך

That is, he explains that even if the intent is a command, the verse is implying that even *if* you only have silver to lend (as opposed to gold), you nevertheless must. In this merit, God who is with the poor, will similarly be with you, and will make you wealthy.